# How do I add a copy of a git repo to an omnibus package?

Tags: omnibus

I have an existing Omnibus package and source. I would like to add a copy of a directory of a git repo.

So I added the following code:

```
name "REPO_NAME"
source :git => "https://github.com/REPO_NAME"
```

and the content even appears on the version_manifest.json

but it wasn't copied over.

when I tried to add:

```
command "cp -r REPO_NAME TARGETPATH"
```

i got the error:

```
cp: cannot stat `REPO_NAME': No such file or directory
```

as part of the build log.

Also, it adds the git sha to the name of the package.
All I want is to simply distribute a copy of the git repo alongside the package.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added:

```
build do
  command "cp -r ../REPO_NAME APP_INSTALL_PATH"
end
```